# How do I get rid of a follower in Skyrim if I'm pretty sure she's dead?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'd had a Dark Brotherhood initiate follow me for some time. A while back though, I'm almost positive I killed her (I think I was annoyed with her -- might've been in the way of a door or something). I don't know if I'd saved, but either way she's no longer "following" me. I've tried to have other people follow me since then, but they all say something to the tune of "Looks like you've already got someone with you." I don't know if I did actually kill her, but even if I hadn't wouldn't she have grown tired of waiting if that were the issue? I've retraced my steps several times, went back to the Dawnstar Sanctuary to see if she had returned, even tried going through old save slots. Is it possible it's a glitch? Or is there a way to fix it?

Alternatively, is it possible to sacrifice her in Boethiah's Calling in order to get rid of her, or would I need her to actually follow me? (I've never done the quest so I wouldn't know.)

> [EDIT: To the people marking this as a duplicate of "How do I get Skyrim to recognize I don't have a follower anymore?", this is not as I am not using PC, I am using Xbox, and therefore cannot use console commands. The other suggestion on that page said to reload, which I have before. I promise, I've researched this many times. If such an answer already existed I wouldn't be asking.]

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: I'm using console.

Comment: Specifically Xbox.

Comment: You should try adding a bounty to that once you have enough rep, and ask for Xbox answers.